# Starting a class in Java, but different

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Computer science class we started classes in Java Eclipse like so:

```
public class FirstApp extends Applet implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener 

{
```

Not the way I see it everywhere else:

```
class FirstApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
}
```

What's the difference? What would happen if I changed a piece of my code to the second one?

Comment: You should search what `extends` and `implements` means.

Comment: The difference is basically that the first snippet is an applet, the second a normal application. You've probably declared a `public void start()` method in the first one, in which you've written the code to be run.

Comment: Just look it up instead of asking here. There are lots of resources and they are super easy to find.

Comment: When using `extends Applet`, you start your application in an already created graphical context, or said otherwise, application sub component. When doing `static void main(String[] args)`, your application starts in its own vm

Comment: How would I "look it up" what the hell keywords if I don't know what I'm searching for?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that your first example uses [Applet technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/), which is now widely deprecated. The browser will run it for you inside a JVM which it creates.

> A Java applet is a special kind of Java program that a browser enabled
>   with Java technology can download from the internet and run. An applet
>   is typically embedded inside a web page and runs in the context of a
>   browser. An applet must be a subclass of the java.applet.Applet class.
>   The Applet class provides the standard interface between the applet
>   and the browser environment.

Your second example is a Java application designed to be invoked directly by the JVM. Command line arguments will be passed as a String array into `main()`. i.e.

```
java -cp . org.example.FirstApp
```

Answer (score 0):

As Adam pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42485326/), the difference between both examples is that the first program is a Java Applet and the second a normal Java Application.

### The applet

The applet is run in your browser which will start a Java interpreter for you and create the applet. After the creation of an applet, the method `init()` is called by the Java interpreter, when initialized, the applet will be started via the method `start()`. In your first example, no code is run.

To add some code to execute, you have to implement the `start()` method, which will make your applet look like this:

```
public class FirstApp extends Applet implements ActionListener,
    MouseListener, MouseMotionListener 
{
   public void start() {
      // Code to execute when started
   }
}
```

The interfaces implemented are event listeners that enable the applet to react to certain user events. A normal application does not necessarily implement these as command line application don't need graphical event listeners.

You can either launch your applet from a browser or from Eclipse, like you probably did in your Computer Sciene classes. When an applet is launched via Eclipse, Eclipse takes care of launching and displaying the applet in an own window so you don't have to write the web page in which the applet will be embedded.

### The application

The application is run in a Java interpreter started directly by you, the user. When started, the Java interpreter runs the `main(String[])` method, so the equivalent to the upper example would be:

```
public class FirstApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Code to execute when started
    }
}
```

After you've compiled it (via `javac FirstApp.java`), a normal application can be started via command line, like this:

```
java FirstApp
```

Of course, applications can also be launched (i. e. compiled and interpreted) through Eclipse with the "Launch" button.